# C++ error expected class-name before '{' token

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, sdl, derived-class

I know many, many others have posted about this but I am so lost, due to so many people saying forward declaration and other massively confusing things that I can't seem to find a way to use without bringing up new errors in my compiler so if anyone could help me that would be much appreciated.

I am using Code::Blocks on Ubuntu 15.04

The Error is `OptimizedSurface.h|11|error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token`

In the OptimizedSurface Header file I decided to do `class OptimizedSurface : Game{` because before this error I was getting

`include/Game.h|18|error: invalid use of member ‘Game::windowSurface’ in static member function` the line was optimized_surface = SDL_ConvertSurface(surface, Game::windowSurface->format, 0);

And now the the code is the below files.

main.cpp -

```
#include "Game.h"
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char* args[]){
    printf("Initializing Game class\n");
    Game game = Game();
    return 0;
}
```

Game.h -

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include "SDL2/SDL_image.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include "MenuState.h"

class MenuState;

class Game{
    public:
        Game();
        virtual ~Game();
        SDL_Surface *windowSurface = nullptr;

    protected:

    private:
        void tick();
        void update_time();
        std::chrono::system_clock::time_point now, last_frame;
        int delta = 0;
        void event_handler();
        void render();

        // Screen Dimensions
        const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
        const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

        //Main Window
        SDL_Window *window = nullptr;

        // Surfaces
        SDL_Surface *currentImage = nullptr;

        // Main Menu Screen
        MenuState *menu;

        bool isRunning = true;

        // Main Menu = 1; Game = 2; Paused = 3;
        int currentState = 1;

        // Events
        SDL_Event ev;
};

#endif // GAME_H
```

Game.cpp -

```
#include "Game.h"


Game::Game(){
    // Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );

    else{
        this->menu = new MenuState;
        // Create Window
        this->window = SDL_CreateWindow( "Tetris", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );

        if( this->window == NULL ){
            printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        }

        else{
            // Get window surface
            this->windowSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( this->window );

            // Fill the surface white
            SDL_FillRect( this->windowSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB( this->windowSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );

            // Update the Surface
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( this->window );

            //Set current image to display as main menu
            this->currentImage = this->menu->MenuSurface[ 0 ];
            this->tick();
        }
    }
}

void Game::tick(){
    while( this->isRunning ){
        if( !( this->delta >= 33 ) )
            this->update_time();
        else{
            this->last_frame = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            this->event_handler();
            this->render();
        }
    }
}

void Game::update_time(){
    this->now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    this->delta = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(this->now - this->last_frame).count();
}

void Game::event_handler(){
    while( SDL_PollEvent( &this->ev ) != 0 && this->currentState == 1){
        switch( this->ev.type ){
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if( this->ev.button.button  == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT )
                    if( this->menu->checkPos( this->ev.button.x, this->ev.button.y ) )
                        this->currentImage = this->menu->MenuSurface[ 2 ];
                    break;

            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if( this->ev.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT )
                    if( this->menu->checkPos( this->ev.button.x, this->ev.button.y ) )
                        currentState = 2;
                        // Start the Game
            default:
                if( this->menu->checkPos( this->ev.button.x, this->ev.button.y ) )
                    this->currentImage = this->menu->MenuSurface[ 1 ];
                else
                    this->currentImage = this->menu->MenuSurface[ 0 ];
                break;
        }
    }
    if( this->ev.type == SDL_QUIT )
        this->isRunning = false;
}

void Game::render(){
    SDL_BlitSurface( this->currentImage, NULL, windowSurface, NULL );
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );
}

Game::~Game(){
    // Destroy Everything
    this->currentImage = nullptr;

    SDL_DestroyWindow( this->window );
    this->window = nullptr;

    delete menu;

    // Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

MenuState.h -

```
#ifndef MENUSTATE_H
#define MENUSTATE_H

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include "OptimizedSurface.h"
#include <string>


class MenuState{
    public:
        MenuState();
        virtual ~MenuState();

        bool checkPos( int x, int y );

        SDL_Surface *MenuSurface[ 3 ];

        int buttonX [ 2 ];
        int buttonY [ 2 ];

    protected:

    private:
};

#endif // MENUSTATE_H
```

MenuState.cpp -

```
#include "MenuState.h"


MenuState::MenuState(){
    for( int i = 1; i <= 3; ++i){
        this->MenuSurface[ i-1 ] = OptimizedSurface::convert( "assets/menu/" + std::to_string(i) + ".jpg" );
    }
    this->buttonX[ 0 ] = 250;
    this->buttonX[ 1 ] = buttonX[ 0 ] + 140;

    this->buttonY[ 0 ] = 36;
    this->buttonY[ 1 ] = buttonY[ 0 ] + 100;
}

bool MenuState::checkPos( int x, int y ){
    if( this->buttonX[ 0 ] < x && x < this->buttonX[ 1 ] )
        if( this->buttonY[ 0 ] < y && y < this->buttonY[ 1 ] )
            return true;
    return false;
}

MenuState::~MenuState(){
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i ){
        SDL_FreeSurface( this->MenuSurface[ i ] );
        this->MenuSurface[ i ] = nullptr;
    }
}
```

OptimizedSurface.h -

```
#ifndef OPTIMIZEDSURFACE_H
#define OPTIMIZEDSURFACE_H

#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include "SDL2/SDL_image.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>


class OptimizedSurface : public Game{
    public:
        OptimizedSurface();
        static SDL_Surface *convert( std::string filepath );
        virtual ~OptimizedSurface();
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // OPTIMIZEDSURFACE_H
```

OptimizedSurface.cpp -

```
#include "OptimizedSurface.h"


OptimizedSurface::OptimizedSurface(){
}

SDL_Surface *OptimizedSurface::convert( std::string filepath ){
    SDL_Surface *optimized_surface = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface *surface = IMG_Load(filepath.c_str());
    if( surface == NULL ){
        printf( "Error Optimizing Surface: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    }
    else{
        optimized_surface = SDL_ConvertSurface(surface, windowSurface->format, 0);
        if( optimized_surface == NULL )
            printf( "Error Optimizing Surface: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    }
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);

    return optimized_surface;
}

OptimizedSurface::~OptimizedSurface(){
}
```

Comment: If there is no way to fix it I will probably just move Game::windowSurface to another class as to stop the cyclic inclusion

Comment: Why are you including `OptimizedSurface.h` in `MenuState.h` where you are not using it at all ? Also your next error is "can't access non static member in a static member function". Your idea of making `OptimizedSurface` inherit from `Game` to access that member doesn't really make sense. Just pass that member to your `convert` function as a parameter.

Comment: @Leiaz So I am using OptimizedSurface in MenuState.cpp, so should I include it there instead? and I don't know how I would pass Game::windowSurface to OptimizedSurface::convert() function because I will be using this convert function from MenuState and others to come. So I'm still clueless about how to fix access to Game::windowSurface because I cannot pass it as a parameter because I am not using it in Game.cpp but I am using it in MenuState.cpp

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you follow the error message, it says:
`OptimizedSurface.h|11|error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token`

Take a look at OptimizedSurface.h, line 11.  You have:
`class OptimizedSurface : public Game{`

There's nothing wrong with that, but the error is saying that the identifier right before the '{' is not recognized.  That identifier is `Game`.  So for some reason, `Game` is not declared before you get to line 11.

Looking at the headers included by OptimizedSurface.h, you probably expect it to be declared in "Game.h".  So now look at Game.h.  It does indeed have a declaration for the `Game` class.  But *before* that, there is an `#include "MenuState.h"`.  You should guess that this is interfering.

In MenuState.h, you have `#include "OptimizedSurface.h"`...

Does it make sense yet?  It's a circular #include pattern.  Your `OptimizedSurface` needs to know about `Game`, but Game.h is trying to declare `OptimizedSurface` (via MenuState.h) first!  OptimizedSurface.h depends on Game.h, Game.h depends on MenuState.h, and MenuState.h depends on OptimizedSurface.h.

The best solution is to remove the `#include "OptimizedSurface.h"` from MenuState.h.  MenuState does not actually depend on OptimizedSurface, so there's no need for it.  It just contributes to a mess of header dependencies.

If you do have an *implementation* dependency, then you should #include the appropriate headers in the cpp files.  You mentioned that MenuState.cpp depends on OptimizedSurface, so add `#include "OptimizedSurface.h"` to MenuState.cpp instead of in MenuState.h.

Besides fixing it by removing unnecessary dependencies, you can in some cases solve a circular dependency pattern by adding a "forward declaration" of dependent classes (see a good C++ reference for more).  This is important for complicated dependencies, but should not be the solution you use this time.